# Having trouble extending and implementing for the same class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, extending

So I have a class that adds nine `JButtons` to a container, but am having trouble implementing a way for the buttons to actually do anything.  I'm trying to make a rudimentary Tic Tac Toe game the simply places an X on the first button you click, O on the second, etc. I figured I could use `ActionListener`, but since I made my own class called Interface which already extends `JFrame`, I figured I could implement `ActionListener`.  Doing this results in a "cannot find symbol" error on line 4.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public Interface ()
    {
        super("Panel");

        //Creates the window
        Container c;
        c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3, 5, 5));          

        //Creates the buttons  
        JButton tLeft = new JButton(" ");
        JButton tMiddle = new JButton(" ");
        JButton tRight = new JButton(" ");
        JButton mLeft = new JButton(" ");
        JButton mMiddle = new JButton(" ");
        JButton mRight = new JButton(" ");
        JButton bLeft = new JButton(" ");
        JButton bMiddle = new JButton(" ");
        JButton bRight = new JButton(" ");
        c.add(tLeft);
        c.add(tMiddle);
        c.add(tRight);
        c.add(mLeft);
        c.add(mMiddle);
        c.add(mRight);
        c.add(bLeft);
        c.add(bMiddle);
        c.add(bRight);


        setSize(250,250);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
      Interface Message=new Interface();
        Message.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

This is still my first semester of Java so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.  My mistake is probably really obvious, but after a couple hours of searching I still just don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ActionListener` is in the `java.awt.event` package. You will need to import this package as importing `java.awt.*` doesn't include sub-packages.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```